# PHP preg_replace string with value of variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to use regex in php to find all strings that starts with "$" and replacing it with the appropriate variable. For example:

```
$value = "Some Value";
<b>$value</b>
```

Where the end result should be:

```
<b>Some Value</b>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
ob_start("tagreplace");


function tagreplace ( $tagreplace ) 
{

    $value1 = "Some Value";
    $pattern = '/(?<=\s)(\$[^#\s]+)(?=\s)/';

    $tagreplace = preg_replace( $pattern , '<?php echo $0 ?>', $tagreplace);

    return $tagreplace;
}

/* html files for combining */
include 'main_content.html';

ob_end_flush();
```

But this doesn't seem to work... I've tried for loops, while loops, and none of them are working. Basically I am trying to be extremely lazy and use regex to make very shorthand variables that I can put everywhere, replacing the strings like `"$value"` with whatever corresponding value that the variable `$value` has assigned to it.

I understand that `/e` is now deprecated so I can't use that to treat php tags as actual code. I have attempted to use `preg_replace_callback` but this didn't actually do anything. I'm thinking there probably isn't a way to properly do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do here, although if you take a slightly different approach with your regex you'll likely have more success. Essentially it's easier to break the pattern up into three capture groups (the start tag, the value, and the end tag)

```
function tagreplace ( $tagreplace ) {

    $replace = "Some Value";
    $pattern = '/(.+>)(.+)(<.+)/m';
    $tagreplace = preg_replace( $pattern, '$1'.$replace.'$3', $tagreplace);
    return $tagreplace;
}

$value = "Old Value";
echo tagreplace("<b>$value</b>");

echo "\n -- Using \$value slightly different-- \n";

$value = "<b>$value</b>";
echo tagreplace($value);
```

By using a more generic pattern you should be able swap out `$value`, regardless if it's the entire value, or if it's what is between the  `< >` tags. When in doubt use a regex tester (linked below) and you might be able to eliminate several recursive loops, *or* going around in circles.

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/rW8lC6/1

Comment: That's not quite there. I must apologize, allow me to be more clear.

 Initially, I assumed that if the regex pattern finds, for example, $foo, I could then replace it with the php tags around it and that way when <?php echo $foo; ?> is inputted, the server would interpret it as php and not as a string, and echo the actual value of $foo. But upon further research, it appears preg_replace actually interprets the replacement as a string. And that's my dilemma. I just want the strings "$foo" to be replaced with the actual value of "$foo", say, a numerical or string.